# A problem concerning existence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I asked myself does there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that:

If $x\in \mathbb Q$ then $f(x)\in \mathbb R\setminus {\mathbb Q}$ and if $x\in \mathbb R\setminus {\mathbb Q}$ then $f(x)\in \mathbb Q$.

To be honest, I didn`t try much, I know the usual $\epsilon - {\delta}$ definition of a continuous function, also I know about sequential characterization of a continuous function by Heine and that a pre-image of an open set is an open set under a continuous mapping. So far with these methods of defining (characterizing) continuity I couldn´t arrive at a contradiction when supposing non-existence of such a function which guides me in a direction that such a function exists. Now, if it exists I would like that you people give me some hints how could I prove that it exists (if possible without an Axiom of Choice) and if you know that it exists and know of an example of such a function I would like of you to write down that example.

Also be aware that I am no expert in math so I really don´t have a true feeling if this is something trivial or extra hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Clearly such a function is non-constant, so we have some $x,y\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. We can assume WLOG that $f(x)<f(y)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem we have $[f(x),f(y)]$ in the image of $f$. Thus every irrational in $[f(x),f(y)]$ must be in $f(\mathbb Q)$, but the set of such irrationals is uncountable while $f(\mathbb Q)$ is countable, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot happen since $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is uncountable while $\Bbb Q$ is countable. That is, the condition that if $x\in \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, then $f(x)\in\Bbb Q$ cannot happen for all irrational numbers unless $f(x)$ is a constant function, in which case one of the two conditions would not be satisfied.